# Stripe Refund Monthly and Yearly

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a question about refunding in this flow:

**2 Subscriptions -> Monthly 5$, Yearly 45$**

My refunding period is one hour. After one hour the button dissapears and you cannot refund anymore.

My problem is if the user buys monthly for 5$, and then imediately upgrades to Yearly it takes 40$ because of proliferations.

Then i have 2 payment intents that can be refunded in one hour(one for monthly and one for yearly).

And i need to keep them both in my DB and create logic to refund both 5$ monthly an 40$ yearly if the user wants the refund in that hour. Because if not, i will refund 40$ and the user looses 5$ if he executes this flow and i don't want him to loose money if he can refund in 1 hour range.

Is it okay to store both payment intents in DB and refund him like this?

Do you guys see something wrong about this flow or is it a better one?